# JS do ... while

Tags: javascript, do-while

It seems to me that i misunderstand the behavior of the do ... while loop in JS.
Let's say we have a code like:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [];
var c;
do {c = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];
    b.push(c);}
while(c===4);
console.log(b);
```

Which is intended to roll out random item from array `a` if that item is not `4`. 
But if we roll several times we'll see that it doesn't actually prevent `4` from getting to array `b`. Why? I thought that it would work like this:

1. Roll random item from array `a`, store it to `c` and push `c` to `b`;
2. Check if `(c===4)` is `true`;
3. If it is — go to paragraph 1;
4. If it's not — log `b` to console.

Where am I mistaking and why does this code work in such a way? What are others way to 'ban' some item from array from being rolled randomly (except filtering the array) if this approach can't help me?

Comment: You actually said it yourself: you push the item into the array and only then check if it is 4 to exit the loop.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev So, do.. while actually does work as described in ordered list, that I've posted?

Comment: What type of values for `b` are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do while runs and THEN checks.  So it will get a random number from A, store that in C and push that to B, and THEN if C is 4, it will do another loop.

So if C is 4, it will still push it to B, it just won't continue after that.

You could do it like this:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [];
var c = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];
while (c !== 4) {
  b.push(c);
  c = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];
}
console.log(b);
```

I think this is what you're trying to do?  Continuously push a random item from A into B unless you get the result 4, in which case, quit and go to console.log?

Answer (score 1):

As explained by the commenters, you're still pushing `4`. You can avoid it by make it very explicit what happens when.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [];
var c;
var keep_going = true;
while (keep_going) {
    c = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];
    if (c === 4) {
        keep_going = false;
    } else {
        b.push(c);
    }
}
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the way your code is written, you are not "bannning" 4 from being added to `b`. The code you have written will add a value from `a` to `b` and, if the value added equals 4, continue to add values from `a` to `b` until the last value added does not equal 4. So you will get results like:

```
b == [1];
b == [5];
b == [4,1];
b == [4,4,4,4,4,4,3];
```

Since `do-while` is a looping mechanism, I'm assuming you want to keep trying to add a value from `a` to `b` until you find one that is not 4. That would be

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5],
    b = [],
    c;
do {
    c = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];
    if(c!==4) { b.push(c); }
} while(c===4);
console.log(b);
```

This will produce the following values for `b`

```
b == [1];
b == [2];
b == [3];
b == [5];
```